# import a latest vimeo user video into a page

Tags: plugins, vimeo

A user has many video on vimeo website. I want to display the latest video in a page from that videos. How will I do this?

I used the vimeo channel gallery plugin and set the maxitems to 1 and it displays the latest video but the problem is that it also displaying the thumbnail of the video under the video player on the page.

Any one who have some idea how will I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The [Vimeography Developer Bundle](http://vimeography.com/add-ons/developer-bundle/) for the [Vimeography](http://wordpress.org/plugins/vimeography) plugin includes a gallery theme that does just what you are looking for - it is called "Single" and can only be found in the Bundle.

Hope this helps!